# Creating a message collector in a DM channel within the guildMemberAdd event

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm trying to make a message collector in a DM channel but it won't collect any of the messages.
Here's my code:

```js
member.createDM().then(channel => {
    const filter = m => !m.author.bot;
    const collector = channel.createMessageCollector(filter, { max: 1, time: 10000 });
    collector.on('collect', msg => { 
        if (msg == text) {
            let success = new MessageEmbed()
                .setDescription("You have successfully been verified!")
            channel.send(success)
        } else {
            console.log(msg)
        }
    });
    collector.on('end', collected => console.log(`Collected ${collected.size} items`));
    })
```

Comment: Any Errors? - If so please specify. If there are no errors then the code maybe isn't running - could be the filter statement.